# Send attachment from react-native app to AWS connect with ChatJS library

Tags: javascript, react-native, amazon-connect, chatjs

I'm using the Amazon Connect [ChatJS](https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-chatjs) library and trying to send an attachment, but it returns error 400 'Invalid request body'.

ChatJS's `sendAttachment()` method accepts an object with attachment of HTML filetype. I'm using [react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker) to select an image from the device, and converting to `File` before passing it to the `sendAttachment()` method, but it doesn't work. Does anyone know the solution for this?

This is how I'm converting the local `imageUri` to a `File` and triggering the `handleSendAttachment()` function, which will then run the `sendAttachment()` method of amazon-client-chatjs session:

```js
const sendAttachment = async () => {
    if (!attachment?.uri) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      const fileBlob = new Blob([attachment.uri], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
      const file = new File([fileBlob], attachment.name);
      handleSendAttachment(file, clearAttachment);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error: ', err);
    }
};
```